# How to pass string from virtual keyboard in AIR to an embedded HTML Page

Tags: apache-flex, keyboard, air, adobe, virtual

i'm a newbie in Flex/Air. I'm developing an AIR web browser and i want to use a virtual keyboard to write in the HTML pages.

I integrated this component as keyboard: http://www.uibuzz.com/2011/adobe/flex/github-flex-4-component-virtualkeyboard/ it works well when i try to write in a text area, but i don't know how to write in the html page.

**EXAMPLE:**
To write in textarea, i just have to call this:

`textarea.text = event.keyLabel;`

how could i pass the string:

```
event.keyLabel
```

to an:

```
<mx:HTML id="HTML" .../>
```

?

I really hope that is all clear, thank u in advance for your help, and i apologize for my bad english.

Fab

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `htmlText` property

Comment: Thank you for ur fast answer..  already tried this property, and it doesn't work as it should... I try to explain better:
I want to pass the strings to HTML but it has to write in an input box and not on the entire page.
For example if i load google on my HTML object and try to write with the virtual keyboard, it doesn't write on the input search of google, it write on the whole page showing me just the string.

Hope is clear.. :)

Comment: I didn't understand exactly, but the textArea has also a htmlText property if that's what you're looking for

Comment: You r right, my english is not so good.. sorry

To let u to understand i've made a little video, that u can watch here: http://www.fideamedia.altervista.org/video/ so i think u can understand my problem ;)
Thank u so much.

Comment: you said it works well when you write in textArea, you mean you did a simple application containing just a textArea?

Comment: anyway, to achieve what you are trying to do, you can write a javascript function to pass values from flash to html, and then call that function using the ExternalInterface API, you can find a lot of tutorials about it http://www.switchonthecode.com/tutorials/flex-javascript-basics-using-externalinterface

Comment: mm yeah think i have to use JS.. i thought there was a simple command in flex to do that.. Thank you for ur help..